# React-dnd Components not working correctly in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook, react-dnd

I am having some HUGE problems trying to display my drag-and-droppable (react-dnd) components in Storybook. I have two identical components, yet one of my components has its connectDragSource connected correctly in its props, whereas the other one I get undefined ('connectDragSource is undefined').

Component 1 :

```
// @flow
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {DragSource} from "react-dnd/lib/cjs/index";


const collect = (connect, monitor) => {
    return ({
            isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
            connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
            connectDragPreview: connect.dragPreview()
        }
    );

}
const src = {
    beginDrag(props, monitor, component) {
        return {}
    },
};

export class Component1 extends Component<Props, State> {

    render() {
        const {connectDragSource} = this.props;
        if (!connectDragSource) {
            alert("I will never be called!!")
        }
        return (
            <div>11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
        );
    }
}

// $FlowFixMe
export default (DragSource("XY", src, collect)(Component1))
```

Component 2:

```
Component 2: 

// @flow
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {DragSource} from "react-dnd/lib/cjs/index";


const collect = (connect, monitor) => {
    return ({
            isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
            connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
            connectDragPreview: connect.dragPreview()
        }
    );

}
const src = {
    beginDrag(props, monitor, component) {
        return {}
    },
};

export class Component2 extends Component<Props, State> {

    render() {
        const {connectDragSource} = this.props;
        if (!connectDragSource) {
            alert("I will always be called!! connectDragSource is undefined!!")
        }
        return (
            <div>222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222</div>
        );
    }
}

// $FlowFixMe
export default (DragSource("XY", src, collect)(Component2));
```

Yes I **HAVE** remembered to add the DragDropContextProvider. Both my storybooks are also 'identical' :

```
import React from 'react';
import {storiesOf} from '@storybook/react';
import Component1 from "./Component1";

import {withKnobs} from '@storybook/addon-knobs/react';
import "../build/index.a62147863e7177001589.css";
import {DragDropContextProvider} from 'react-dnd'
import HTML5Backend from "react-dnd-html5-backend";

storiesOf('Component1', module)
    .addDecorator(withKnobs)
    .add('1', () => {
        return (
            <DragDropContextProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
                <Component1/>
            </DragDropContextProvider>)
    })
```

...and....

```
import React from 'react';
import {storiesOf} from '@storybook/react';
import {Component2} from "./Component2";

import {withKnobs} from '@storybook/addon-knobs/react';
import {DragDropContextProvider} from "react-dnd";
import HTML5Backend from "react-dnd-html5-backend";

storiesOf('Component2 ', module)
    .addDecorator(withKnobs)
    .add('2', () => {

        return (
            <DragDropContextProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
                <Component2/>
            </DragDropContextProvider>)
    })
```

Why would Component1 have its connectDragSource injected yet Component2 not??

Is the drag and drop of my components somehow interfering with the drag and drop from storybook??

Interestingly if I put my Component2 in the same story as Component1, then Component2 will work :

```
storiesOf('Component1 and Component2', module)
    .addDecorator(withKnobs)
    .add(' - 1 - ', () => {
        return (
            <DragDropContextProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
                <GenericModal/>
            </DragDropContextProvider>)
    })
    .add(' - 2 - ', () => {
        return (
            <DragDropContextProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
                <TableWidget/>
            </DragDropContextProvider>)
    })
    .add(' - 1 again - ', () => {
        return (
            <DragDropContextProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
                <GenericModal/>
            </DragDropContextProvider>)
    })
```

If anyone knows why this behaviour is happening I would love to know why. This problem is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I just realised what my problem is. I have two exports in my Component file :

```
export class Component1 extends Component<Props, State> 

export default (DragSource("XY", src, collect)(Component1))
```

This is really bad because in my storybook I am importing like this :

```
import {Component2} from "./Component2";
```

This basically means the Component2 is being imported, and not the decorated component.

Solution is to remove the export from Component2 like so

```
class Component2 extends Component<Props, State>
```

And remove the curly braces on the storybook like so

```
import Component2 from "./Component2";
```